# VCPKG versions of packages

Tags: vcpkg

is there possibility how to install **older version of packages** by using *vcpkg install*?

I found that there is a file in versions/baseline.json, but even if I change the version of the package there, it always install the newest one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/specifications/versioning.md is what you are looking for. Be aware you need to pass an additional flag to vcpkg to activate that feature. It also only works in manifest mode and not in classic mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the vcpkg documentation about [Pin old Boost versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/examples/modify-baseline-to-pin-old-boost). There are two methods to install a specific version of a package:

> Method 1: Pin specific packages.
> Method 2: Modify baseline